# java method for computing ln(n!) recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, math, recursion

How to implement java method to compute `ln(n!)` recursively?

This is my solution. I know it's wrong but this is the only solution that came to me so far.

```
double func(int n) {
   double result;
   if(n == 1)
     return 1;
   result = func(n-1) * n;
   return Math.log(result);
}
```

This is what the function returns:

```
func(2) = 0.6931471805599453  (correct)
func(3) = 0.7320993680864453  (should be: 1.79175946922805500081)
func(4) = 1.0744553356380115  (should be: 3.17805383034794561964)
```

Comment: Your solution isn't wrong but there are ways to calculate this that can handle larger `n` without overflow.

Comment: If you dont call the method itself, is not recursive call.

Comment: Yes, of course.  You want the lngamma function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html.  Undergraduate factorial implementations, especially the recursive ones, are misguided.

Comment: sorry it is actually **result = func(n-1) * n;**

Comment: `if(n==1) return 0;` since `ln(1!) = ln(1) = 0`

Answer (score 5):

The thing to be aware of is that `ln(n*x) = ln(n) + ln(x)` and `ln(1) = 0`:

```
double func(int n) {
   if(n==1)
     return 0;
   return func(n-1) + Math.log(n);
}
```

Comment: A recursive solution for anything having to do with factorials is easy to code but hopelessly naive.

Comment: That's what I was talking about ... method "func" calling itself "func". That is a recursive call.

Comment: I say that's a bad idea.  You should understand why.

Comment: @duffymo because we're taking `ln` of `n!` we have, for example for `n = 3`, `ln(3!) = ln(3*2*1) = ln(3) + ln(2) + ln(1)`. So, you see, there aren't _really_ factorials involved. So this should be `O(n)` and the numbers involved will be rather small...

Comment: That's as long as n is small.  lngamma is better for large values.  Ought to used in either case.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, it's hard to refute gamma function in this case. See [mathematical hacker](http://www.evanmiller.org/mathematical-hacker.html), scroll down, although I agree that OP wants a recursive implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You want the gamma function, because gamma(n) = (n-1)!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Even better yet, lngamma has nice properties that make calculating n!/m!(n-m)! easy.

Don't use the naive recursive factorial that students love so much.  It's inefficient (no tail recursion in Java; no memoization) and limited if you return a type other than double. Better to return a double.

Comment: Recursion without tail recursion will still be inefficient for large n.  My point is that there's a better way, one that most people are not familiar with.  Gamma function and its relationship to factorial is well known to anyone who has studied Bessel functions and the method of Frobenius for solving ODEs, but that's not your run of the mill developer.   It's worth knowing.

Comment: I entirely agree that you should [math the shit out it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6lYeTWdYLw) (youtube link), I just think that possibly a little maths at a time - basic log arithmetic first, everything else later...

Comment: Apache Commons offers an [implementation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Gamma.html#gamma(double)).